# What is an appharbor worker...exactly?

Tags: appharbor

The Appharbor [pricing page](https://appharbor.com/pricing) defines a worker something you increase to "Improve the reliability and responsiveness of your website". But in trying to compare price with others such as aws, I am having a hard time defining what a worker is exactly.

Anyone have a better definition than "more is better"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this thread](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3545593):

> AppHarbor is a multitenant platform and we're running multiple
>   application on each application server. A worker is an actual worker
>   process that is limited in terms of the amount of resources it can
>   consume.
>
> ...
>
> 2 workers will always be on two different machines. We're probably
>   going to reuse machines when you scale to more than that and increase
>   process limits instead (this could yield better performance as you
>   need to populate fewer local cache etc.)

Comment: Good find...thanks. from your link I was able to find this one - 
https://appharbor.com/page/programpolicy which states some limits like:

Worker Network Bandwidth: 100GB/month - Soft

Shared DB processing: Max 200msec per second CPU time - Soft

Request timeout: 30 seconds - Soft; 180 seconds - Hard

Worker RAM usage: 512MB - Soft; 1024MB - Hard